# Suppress object finalization until other thread running

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose I have some code in class in which one method returns result immediately, but before that invokes a background task.

```
class CalculationPolicy 
{
    private readonly IRequestContext _reqContext;

    public CalculationPolicy(IRequestContext reqContext)
    {
       _reqContext = reqContext;
    }

    public ProcessResult Process(object model) 
    {
        var response = new ProcessResult();

        // some synchronous processing ... 
          ............................

        // notifications go into other thread
        Task.Run(() => NotifyCallback(model));

        return response;
    }

    private void NotifyCallback(object model)
    {
       // some notification logic
       // that uses a field [_reqContext]
       string email = _reqContext.GetEmailFromClaims();
    }
}
```

I wonder if the Garbage Collector knows that the instance of my class SHOULD NOT be finalized until the method NotifyCallback is finished on other thread in the way that the state of my object remains untouched by Garbage Collector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object will be collected when there's no more references pointing to it. When scheduling your task:

```
Task.Run(() => NotifyCallback(model));
```

The delegate has an implicit reference to your object, therefore it won't be collected until the task runs.

But to nitpick a bit, your question was specifically:

> I wonder if the Garbage Collector knows that the instance of my class SHOULD NOT be finalized **until the method NotifyCallback is finished** on other thread

Your object could be collected in the middle of `NotifyCallback` if it stops referencing `this`. For instance:

```
private void NotifyCallback(object model)
{
   // some notification logic
   // that uses a field [_reqContext]
   string email = _reqContext.GetEmailFromClaims();

   // Do some stuff with email but do not access any field
   // From this point, the object can be collected at any time
   Console.WriteLine(email);   

   Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

Technically, your object could be collected at any point after `string email = _reqContext.GetEmailFromClaims();`. This shouldn't be a problem since you're not using any field from the class anymore. In the rare case where it would be an issue (typically when doing interop with native code), you can use `GC.KeepAlive` to hold a reference and artificially extend the lifetime of your object:

```
private void NotifyCallback(object model)
{
   // some notification logic
   // that uses a field [_reqContext]
   string email = _reqContext.GetEmailFromClaims();

   // Do some stuff with email but do not access any field
   Console.WriteLine(email);   

   Console.WriteLine("Done");

   GC.KeepAlive(this); // The GC won't collect the object before this line
}
```

But really you should be fine in most cases.

Comment: Yes, although the "could be collected in the middle of" is an optimization that should be invisible to the C# programmer.

Comment: @bommelding Definitely. But the wording of the question was so precise that I felt the need to be equally precise in the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The delegate `() => NotifyCallback(model)` holds a reference to your object because `NotifyCallback` is an instance method. Therefore as long as the Task created by `Task.Run` executes this delegate, your object is not a candidate for garbage collection.